# Delphi XE2 Sort Tstringlist by Filename

Tags: sorting, delphi

I have a series of files that have various file paths and filenames in, all the file names have the same extension but the directory names or paths are all different and have set about loading the files into a Tstringlist and I am trying to sort them into filename order even though they have the paths as well.

Here is an example of the strings in the Tstringlist:-

```
c:\directory 1\AboutUs.lnk
c:\directory something\AAHelp.lnk
c:\directory anything\AAATalk.lnk
```

When sorted by the filename part of the string I would like to end up with.

```
c:\directory anything\AAATalk.lnk
c:\directory something\AAHelp.lnk
c:\directory 1\AboutUs.lnk
```

In other words I would like to be able to sort the strings with path by the filename part of the string.

Any help would be appreciated!.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `TStringList.CustomSort()`:

```
function Compare(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := CompareStr(
    LowerCase(ExtractFileName(List[Index1])),
    LowerCase(ExtractFileName(List[Index2]))
  );
end;

// Then, just call:
YourStrList.CustomSort(Compare);
```

Comment: This approach will work but it could have quite poor performance. Why? Because in this approach you are calling `ExtractFileName` twice for each comparison. Now how many comparisons are needed is largely dependent on which sorting algorithm is used. So I would recommend preparing the data (extracting file names) before doing any sorting. This could speed up the process significantly since you would need to call `ExtractFileName` only once for each list item.

Comment: Or perhaps a even better approach would be to prepare your data so that it is stored as pair of strings where one string represents file path and the other one represents the file name. This would also allow you to implement so called `multi-parameter` sorting where you would initially sort your data based on file names and when you would have multiple files with the same name you would further sort them by their path.

Comment: @SilverWarior, I understand your point about optimization. You can post an answer implementing your idea and I'd be happy to suggest changing the accepted answer.

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback, as I am just venturing back into Delphi after many years away from programming and to be honest my poor old brain does not hold information as well these days but hopefully when I pick up the threads again I will be able to move forward. Just tried the updated version, and the lowercase solved the Capitals problem so an excellent result!.

Comment: @MichaelGeraghty, I'm happy to contribute. I think that this is what a community is made for. Good luck in your way back.

Comment: Thank you, I was about to start looking at a regex search of the Tstringlist but am only just getting back into the syntax and your solution means I may get a nights sleep for the first time this week.

Comment: @karliwson Not sure if I'll have time for this today since there is a 10 hour shift ahead of me (unfortunately not in IT sector). So I'll try to do it in the next few days. Hope I don't forget.

Comment: Don't use LowerCase here. The CompareText function performs case insensitive comparison. Or AnsiCompareText for locale aware case  insensitive comparison.

Comment: Thank you for the addition David, the routine works fine for my needs but good to know of the extra functions that can be used.